Quiero cetrar un PopUp para moviles y web y que se cierre cuando pulsas o clickeas la X
Estoy atorada en esto y ya no sé qué más hacer >_<. Estoy implementando un popup para un cliente con una web en EAM. El sistema normalmente usa plantillas para todo pero no tienen ninguna para popup. He implementado la que he adjuntado pero por todos los medios no puedo hacer que se centre en equipos móviles y tampoco puedo hacer que cierre al pulsar la X. Algún buen Samaritano que me pueda ayudar? Estoy muy desesperada :'(
Estoy agregando el CSS y el HTML, entiendo que no debería solicitar el Java pero si alguien lo puede completar se lo agradecería muchísimo.


.pop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 3000;
}

.pop .pop-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity:.8;
}

.pop .popMain {
    width: 900px;
    min-height: 200px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -430px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.popMiddle p {
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #666;
    padding: 8px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.popMiddle p a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-style: italic;
}

.pop .close {
    padding: 1% 2%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background-image: url(/etc.clientlibs/xxxxxxx/clientlibs/consumer/global/clientlib-common/resources/images/icon-svg-close.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) { .pop .popMain { width: 500px; margin-left: -250px; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;} }

@media (max-width:600px) { .pop .popMain { width: 300px; margin-left: -150px; } .pop .close {width: 20px; right: 12px;}
}

@media (max-width:420px) { .pop .popMain { width: 300px; margin-left: -150px; left: 45%; margin-top: 60px;}
}
<div class="pop">
    <div class="pop-bg">
    </div>
    <div class="popMain" style="top: 99px; margin-left: -430px;">
        <div class="close">
           <span style="display: none;">X</span>
        </div>
                <div class="popMiddle">
                    <p><u><b>Estimados clientes</b></u></p>
                    <p></p>
                    <p>A partir del 22 de abril de este año se iniciará la tercera fase del plan de bloqueo de celulares reportados como robados y con IMEI alterado, con el fin de desincentivar el robo y comercio ilegal de equipos móviles.</p>
                    <p>Les compartimos el landing oficial que el Ministerio de Transportes y Telecomunicaciones del Perú preparó con la información necesaria: <a href="https://sociedadtelecom.pe/landing/bloqueodecelulares/">https://sociedadtelecom.pe/landing/bloqueodecelulares/</a></p>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>




El elemento <dialog> tiene soporte en todos los navegadores modernos (¡un 96%!). ¿Por qué no usar ese que te traerá buena parte de la funcionalidad directamente sin necesidad de tener que implementarla?

Gracias por contestar. Ya lo hice pero parece que el sistema EAM no agarra bien el  y no lo muestra en las previsualizaciones.
